# How to read text files based on their names?

Tags: r, text

I have text files in one folder `fm`,this folder has for each site three measurements with different names but they share the name of the site. The structure of the names are similar. I have another folder `st` where the structure of the name of files is different but the name of the site is included somewhere in the file name. I want to plot the three measurements in `fm`with corresponding file (site name) in `sm`.

I can read all files as:

```
   wgl= read.table("C:\\Users\\wg_ave.txt", sep ='' , header =TRUE)
```

I can do this manually very easy but as I have several files I would like to write a function to read the corresponding files and do this for all files in the folders.

```
  First step:Search in folder `fm`files with the same site name
  Wgl: l_name of the site
  Wgk: k_name of the site
  Wger: er_name of the site
```

Read them:

```
      Wgl= read.table("C:\\Users\\wg_ave.txt", sep ='' , header =TRUE)
       etc….
```

Search the name of this site in folder `sm` and read it

```
wgsitu= read.table("C:\\Users\\wlkave.txt", sep ='' , header =TRUE)
```

Do calculations,plot, whatever

```
        cor(Wgl$va,wgsitu$fg)
        cor(Wgk$va,wgsitu$fg)
        cor(Wger$va,wgsitu$fg)
```

loop for the other sites

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this: (very raw-code)

```
files <- list.files("path-to-folder/fm", pattern = "Your File-Pattern", full.names = TRUE)
```

**Version A:**
If the sitenames are saved in a column of the files:

```
Wgl <- lapply(files, read.table, sep = '', header = TRUE)
```

Then you extract the sitenames

```
site_names <- sapply(Wgl, function(x) {x$sitename_column})
```

(this assumes that all files have the same column that contains the site-names)

**Version B:**
If the sitenames are a part of the filenames `files`

```
site_names <- gsub("pattern of pre and suffixes", files)
```

**Reading the Data**
As done in Version A

```
site_file_names <- list.files("path-to-folder/sm", pattern = paste0(site_names, collapse = "|"), full.names = TRUE)
dat <- lapply(files, read.table, sep = '', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: which makes it even easier as you just have to extract the site_names from the files with something like
`site_names <- gsub("pattern of pre and suffixes", files)`

Habe a look at `?gsub` on how this works

Answer (score 1):

A loop through the site names could be easier:

```
        #set your directory
        setwd("C:\\Users\\fm")

        #you get the list of files in the directory
        lista<-list.files() 

        #example (don't run)
        #lista<-c("l_new","k_new","er_new","l_old","k_old","er_old")

        # I want a loop for each site. Suppose we have 2 sites old and new
        my_site<-c("new","old")


        for (i in 1:length(mysite)) {

        setwd("C:\\Users\\fm")
        #get the 3 files of i site
        files<-grep(my_site[i],lista,fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE)

        Wgl<- read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\fm\\","l_",my_site[i],".txt",sep="")    , sep ='' , header =TRUE)
        Wgk<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\fm\\","k_",my_site[i],".txt",sep="")    , sep ='' , header =TRUE)
        Wger<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\fm\\","er_",my_site[i],".txt",sep="")   , sep ='' , header =TRUE)

          setwd("C:\\Users\\st")
         Wgl_file<-grep(wgl,list.files(),fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE)
         Wgl_site<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\st\\",Wgl_file,sep="")  , sep ='' , header =TRUE)

        Wgk_file<-grep(Wgk,list.files(),fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE)
         Wgk_site<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\st\\",Wgk_file,sep="")  , sep ='' , header =TRUE)

        Wger_file<-grep(Wger,list.files(),fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE)
         Wger_site<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\st\\", Wger_file,sep="")  , sep ='' , header =TRUE)

[...]
        }
```

Comment: I din't understand good this step of your question. I tried to edit my answer

Comment: Maybe I understood better reading your comment to Floo0 answer. I edited again!

Comment: So the las step could be just: `setwd("C:\\Users\\st");
    st_file<-grep(my_site[i],list.files(),fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE);
    st_site<-read.table(paste("C:\\Users\\st\\",st_file,sep="")  , sep ='' , header =TRUE);`  ?

Comment: files was to check if gre worked good. If it returns  `character(0) `something is wrong. `my_site[i]` is the name of the site? `list.files()` gives you the interested files? `getwd()` is the corrected directory?